# How to upload react.js site on cpanel?

Tags: reactjs, upload, hosting, cpanel, namecheap

I have finished my project in react.js. Now I am trying to upload my project on cpanel, but unable to do so. I search it several time but didn't find any suitable solution for it.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upload your files to your hosting package.

You need to run `yarn run build`

Follow this:

https://youtu.be/fR_a3Yp3iGk

Then upload the content from the `/build` folder.

Comment: here uploading means "Deploy"

Comment: Can you expand please?

Comment: I create my projecct in react.js. Now i want to make it live or deploy it on cpanel for commercial use.

Comment: @ShahrukhFazli, you all sorted?

Comment: @ShahrukhFazli if this answer solved your issue, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.